# Comparar cadenas de caracteres en C

Tags: c

Tengo en un arreglo de dos dimensiones de varios nombres de personas(nombre, apellido paterno y apellido materno) y quiero compararlo con un nombre que el usuario introduzca(se almacena en un arreglo de una dimensión) para ver si este se encuentra en el registro, pero creo que las dimensiones de los arreglos no me permite hacerlo. Alguna solución?

Comment: Tienes algo de código para revisarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo correctamente dices que tienes una lista muy larga de nombres por lo que no es optimo iterar a través de todos ellos comparando los nombres.

La solución de este problema es muy simple: Tienes que ordenarlo, lo desordenado siempre es difícil de encontrar incluso en la vida real pero si lo ordenas puedes usar algo como un algoritmo de búsqueda binaria para encontrar rápidamente el valor que buscas.

Claro insertar algo nuevo en la lista es una operación mas costosa así pero bueno hay unos cuantos algoritmos que puedes elegir según la relación costo de inserción/costo de búsqueda que necesites.